# Is there a way to use DBMS_Alert to notify a Winform application of a database change

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, plsql

I am trying to get a winform app to refresh an embedded browser on a database change using Oracle 10g. The only problem is that I am not allowed to use Database Change Notification.  I am curious if anyone has a way of using the built-in package of DBMS_Alert and have had some action happen to a winform app on a database change.

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use Database change Notification? It was made exactly for this type of requirement: "Database Change Notification is a feature that enables client applications to register queries with the database and receive notifications in response to DML or DDL changes on the objects associated with the queries. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do it like this for it to work.  It holds the window in lock until an event occurs i know, but at least it works with DBMS_Alert.  I set this code inside a timer:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("DECLARE\n" + 
                                        "MESSAGE VARCHAR2(1800) := null;\n" +
                                      "STATUS INTEGER;\n" +
                                      "BEGIN\n" +
                                        "DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER('ALERT');\n" +
                                        "DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE('ALERT', MESSAGE, STATUS);\n" + 
                                        "DBMS_ALERT.REMOVE('ALERT');\n" + 
                                      "END;", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
wbMain.Refresh();
conn.Dispose();
```

This gives me what I need.  I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but this is the only solution I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

food for thought...

if you are using ODP, you could use [Oracle Advanced Queuing/Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-nov/o69net-099734.html?ssSourceSiteId=otncn)
and [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/featAQ.htm).

this way your form app can subscribe to a queue and be notified of a change.

This may, however, be massive overkill for your application if you just want to add a new PO # into a drop down!

I have used streams before and it works as expected, but it had a nice level of research and trial & error to get things to click.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use without timer. The below code sample is with background thread

Here is the code snippet

```
privateThread DBMSAlertThread;

private void DBMSAlert(bool Register)
        {
            try
            {
                string sSql;
                if (Register)
                   sSql = "call dbms_alert.register('XYZ')";
                else
                   sSql = "call dbms_alert.remove('XYZ')";
                dbmsAlert = new OracleCommand();
                dbmsAlert.CommandText = sSql;
                dbmsAlert.ExecuteNonQuery();  

                if (Register) //start the background thread
               {
                   DBMSAlertThread = new Thread(AlertEvent);
                   DBMSAlertThread.IsBackground = true;
                   DBMSAlertThread.Start();
               }
            }
            catch (Exception LclExp)
            {
                //Show error or capture in eventlog
            }            
        }

private void AlertEvent(object sender) 
{
    while (true)
    {
        string Message = "";
        int Status = -1;
        bool bStatus;
        OracleParameter param;
        try
        {
            OracleCommand dbmsAlert = new OracleCommand();
            dbmsAlertScan.SQL.Add("call dbms_alert.WaitOne('XYZ', :Message, :Status, 0)"); //Last parameter indicate wait time
            param = new OracleParameter("Message", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            dbmsAlert.Parameters.Add(param); 
            param = new OracleParameter("Status", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            dbmsAlert.Parameters.Add(param); 
            OracleParameter.ExceuteNonQuery();

            Message = dbmsAlert.Parameters["Message"].Value.ToString();
            bStatus = int.TryParse(dbmsAlert.Parameters["Status"].Value.ToString(), out Status);

            if (Status == 0) //0 = Alert Received, 1 = Timed out
            {
                //notify or do ur stuff
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Exp)
        {
            //raise an error
        }
    }
}
```