# DBMS_ALERT usage in Java Servlet

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, plsql, jboss

I'm developing a client/server application using Android as a client and JBoss AS 7.x as the server. I am doing all of this via a servlet and the DataSource is configured to make use of connection pooling.

One of the requirements is to immediately invalidate the client session when certain data from the DataSource(Oracle) is deleted. For this I was checking the DBMS_ALERT.

As far as I can understand DBMS_ALERT needs a polling mechanism that will "hang" the application until a notification occurs. So my servlet will halt all operations and wait for the notification. Please correct me if I'm wrong as I have little to no experience with PL/SQL.

I have already checked the resources provided in this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133757/oracle-database-dbms-alert-usage-with-java-application)** but I didn't manage to understand what's the right track to take.

The code for the DBMS_ALERT **DataSource** side is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER apps0000_datuser_biur
    BEFORE  INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE on apps0000_t
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
    for EACH ROW
begin
    if (deleting) then
        DBMS_ALERT.signal('appdelete',:old.APPS_PACKAGE);
    end if;
end;
```

The code for the DBMS_ALERT **servlet** side is(please correct me if I got something wrong here):

```
try {
    String strDSName1 = "java:/OracleDSJNDI";
    ctx = new InitialContext();
    ds1 = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup(strDSName1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR getting 1'st DS : " + e);
}

 conn = ds1.getConnection();

 String sql = null;
 String message = null;
 String status = null;

 sql = "{call dbms_alert.register('appdelete')}";
 CallableStatement cs1 = conn.prepareCall(sql);
 cs1.execute();
 sql = "{call dbms_alert.waitone('appdelete', ?, ?, ?)}";

 CallableStatement cs2 = conn.prepareCall(sql);
 cs2.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
 cs2.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
 cs2.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);

 int x = 0;

 while (x == 0) {
     cs2.execute();
     String Result = cs2.getString(1);
     System.out.print(Result + "\n");
 }
```

My question is: **How do I implement this in my servlet without causing it to hang when it reaches the DBMS_ALERT part(if it's a viable solution)?**

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the servlet asynchronously to your main application?

Comment: In my case the application IS the servlet. Is this wrong?

Comment: No, not at all. Why don't you want it to hang then? You want it to wait for something to happen... if it's waiting surely it's "hanging"?

Comment: Well, what happens when another user accesses the servlet in order to login/access the DataSource or whatever? Or the current user needs to perform other DS operations. The DBMS_ALERT is supposed to work as a session invalidator flag when a certain permission/record is deleted from the DB.

Comment: I may be missing the point here but you can't have it both ways. You need something to constantly poll; it doesn't have to be every second as long as it's registered you can do other stuff in the meantime. However, whilst you're polling your app will "hang". If this is all your app is doing then it doesn't matter. If it's doing something else then you might want to consider running this asynchronously. The polling can't be the entire app when the it might be doing other things?

Comment: So I should create another class that runs a background thread that's constantly polling the DS waiting for a notification? If yes then how should I write this in such a way that it sends a message to the servlet only to the clients that have their "permissions" deleted from the DB table? I'm sorry if I post rookie questions but I'm not certain how I should approach this.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the message function in the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_alert.htm#i997104), it shows:

```
DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE (
   name      IN   VARCHAR2,
   message   OUT  VARCHAR2,
   status    OUT  INTEGER,
   timeout   IN   NUMBER DEFAULT MAXWAIT);
```

The "timeout" parameters defaults to forever.  The comments state:

```
timeout

Maximum time to wait for an alert.

If the named alert does not occurs before timeout seconds, this returns a status of 1.
```

So, you could set this timeout to some # of seconds, and then poll in a loop.  HOWEVER, I would contend that it is a poor approach, as you are just eating network and application/server resources using polling.  If possible, I would take a look at using Oracle Advanced Queuing which allows for total async processing (See DBMS_AQ package).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll take a look at DBMS_AQ. Meanwhile I have used AsyncTask in order to keep my servlet from waiting for a response.